# Found strange Davik opcode

Tags: android, smali

Who can help me what command meaning:

```
rsub-int/lit8 v9, v0, 0x8.
```

I tried to search, but I got nothing about it.
       Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this](http://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/dalvik-bytecode.html)

Perform twos-complement reverse subtraction op on the indicated register (first argument) and literal value (second argument), storing the result in the destination register.